# Spark jobs submitted through jenkins

Tags: apache-spark, jenkins

I'm looking to deploy a spark jar into a CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins. I have not been able to get spark-submit to work with Jenkins natively. I'm curious if anyone has gone down this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution overlooked there is an arg to disconnect.
--conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like a rightful way to do CI/CD by directly invoking spark-submit.

Consider to decouple job's jar (next Spark application's jar) deployment and submitting a Spark job to a cluster.

One of the solutions, that fits into your requirements is [Spark Job Server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#features)

As an alternative, you could choose to do it in AWS-style, like it's described in [this](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/big-data/implement-continuous-integration-and-delivery-of-apache-spark-applications-using-aws/) document on Spark CI/CD implementation.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you here. I looked at Spark Job Server and also livy, I'm not crazy about using REST API's to deploy jars and both projects are a little green. I went through the AWS link you gave, Its a smart process they layout if you want to use AWS specific tools, but I don't see how they actually deploy to EMR in the end.